# How to know the convention of the XYZ coordinates system that the dataset adopt?

Tags: computational-geometry, raytracing

I'm using ScanNet (http://www.scan-net.org/) dataset. I already have K, the intrinsic parameters matrix, and depth map (depth is positive z-value in the XYZ coordinate system). As far as I know, the XYZ coordinates system will follow right hand rule. Thus, I want to know whether the z-axis points out of the image or points into the image. How can I decide that?